# How to get JSON Strings Difference Percentage

Tags: php, json, compare

Is there any logic/algorithm to compare the two JSON strings with difference percentage. I'm trying to use it to validate the signature which I'm storing as JSON strings.

String 1:

```
[
  {"lx":5,"ly":34,"mx":5,"my":33},
  {"lx":5,"ly":34,"mx":5,"my":34},
  {"lx":6,"ly":32,"mx":5,"my":34},
  {"lx":7,"ly":31,"mx":6,"my":32},
  {"lx":8,"ly":31,"mx":7,"my":31},
  {"lx":9,"ly":30,"mx":8,"my":31},
  {"lx":10,"ly":29,"mx":9,"my":30},
  {"lx":11,"ly":29,"mx":10,"my":29},
  {"lx":11,"ly":28,"mx":11,"my":29}
]
```

String 2:

```
[
  {"lx":5,"ly":33,"mx":5,"my":32},
  {"lx":5,"ly":33,"mx":5,"my":33},
  {"lx":6,"ly":32,"mx":5,"my":33},
  {"lx":7,"ly":32,"mx":6,"my":32},
  {"lx":8,"ly":32,"mx":7,"my":32},
  {"lx":9,"ly":32,"mx":8,"my":32},
  {"lx":10,"ly":31,"mx":9,"my":32},
  {"lx":11,"ly":30,"mx":10,"my":31},
  {"lx":12,"ly":30,"mx":11,"my":30},
  {"lx":13,"ly":29,"mx":12,"my":30}
]
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is the expected result of your example?

Comment: Actually String 1 is the json representation of some lines (means signatures) i have saved it in the database. Now string 2 is again the similar signatures there could be minor changes so I just want to compare the strings so that system can tell that it is a matching signature.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you want to do, but if you just want to check string similarity you can use [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) php command

Sample :

```
$str1 = '{"lx":5,"ly":34,"mx":5,"my":33},
  {"lx":5,"ly":34,"mx":5,"my":34},
  {"lx":6,"ly":32,"mx":5,"my":34},
  {"lx":7,"ly":31,"mx":6,"my":32},
  {"lx":8,"ly":31,"mx":7,"my":31},
  {"lx":9,"ly":30,"mx":8,"my":31},
  {"lx":10,"ly":29,"mx":9,"my":30},
  {"lx":11,"ly":29,"mx":10,"my":29},
  {"lx":11,"ly":28,"mx":11,"my":29}';

  $str2 = '{"lx":5,"ly":33,"mx":5,"my":32},
  {"lx":5,"ly":33,"mx":5,"my":33},
  {"lx":6,"ly":32,"mx":5,"my":33},
  {"lx":7,"ly":32,"mx":6,"my":32},
  {"lx":8,"ly":32,"mx":7,"my":32},
  {"lx":9,"ly":32,"mx":8,"my":32},
  {"lx":10,"ly":31,"mx":9,"my":32},
  {"lx":11,"ly":30,"mx":10,"my":31},
  {"lx":12,"ly":30,"mx":11,"my":30},
  {"lx":13,"ly":29,"mx":12,"my":30}';

  $percent = 0;

  echo similar_text($str1,$str2,$percent).' equal chars'.PHP_EOL;
  echo $percent.'% similarity';
```

Gives you :

```
269 equal chars
78.425655976676% similarity
```

Comment: That is quite close to what I am looking for. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

String distance can be calculated with the [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function

Too bad it is limited to strings no longer than 255 characters.